# ELK host.ip has conflicting data types in the kong-* index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using ELK version 8.10.x for Kong API Gateway logs. In Kibana dashboard I found that `host.ip` has conflict data type. After investigation, I found that there is one index call **kong-01** has `host.ip` field as `text` type while the other indices is `ip` type.

This conflict causing issues when visualizing the data.

How to modify the data type for `host.ip` field to be `ip` type for the existing index please?

This is the current mappings configuration for **kong-01** index:

```
{
  "kong-01": {
    "mappings": {
      "host.ip": {
        "full_name": "host.ip",
        "mapping": {
          "ip": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to create a new index using the below command:

```
PUT kong-01-new
{
  "mappings": {
    "host.ip": {
      "full_name": "host.ip",
      "mapping": {
        "ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I have got the below errors:

```
{

  "error": {

    "root_cause": [

      {

        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",

        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [host.ip : {mapping={ip={type=ip}}, full_name=host.ip}]"

      }

    ],

    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",

    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [host.ip : {mapping={ip={type=ip}}, full_name=host.ip}]",

    "caused_by": {

      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",

      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [host.ip : {mapping={ip={type=ip}}, full_name=host.ip}]"

    }

  },

  "status": 400

}
```

After Re-index completed, I have got the below error for kong01-new index:

```
Index lifecycle error

illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [kong] does not point to index [kong-01-new]
```

I re-indexed again using the same naming convention of ilm_pattern-> "{now/d}-000001" configured in logstash for the new index but still getting the below error:

```
Index lifecycle error

illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [kong] does not point to index [kong-2022-11-24-000001]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform reindex and remove the old index with wrong mapping. Here are the steps:

**UPDATED** - **Create a new index with the proper mapping**

```
PUT kong-01-new
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "host": {
        "properties": {
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Run the reindex**

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "kong-01"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "kong-01-new"
  }
}
```

**Copy the task_id and wait until the reindex completed**

```
GET _tasks/{task_id from the output of reindex API}
```

**Remove the old index and add old index alias to the new index**

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove_index":
      {
        "index": "kong-01"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "kong-01-new",
        "alias": "kong-01"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Image added to show the alias.**
[image]

Comment: Updated the question with the result.

Comment: question updated with an error after re-indexing process.

Comment: check this one for alias point error. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/index-lifecycle-error-handling.html#_index_lifecycle_rollover_alias_x_does_not_point_to_index_y